# Load Image from Jar: Always null

Tags: java, image, null

Looked at other posts on SO and they did not solve this issue.

I'm trying to load an image from my jar file. It is continuously coming up as null. The image is located under:

```
.Jar file > images > BLOCK.png
```

To load the image I am doing:

```
BufferedImage bImg;
URL url = getClass().getResource("/images/BLOCK.png");
try {
    bImg = ImageIO.read(url);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(TileEngine.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

url is null as is bImg.

Do not worry about case sensitivity as I've already checked that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this :

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/images/BLOCK.png"));
```

Comment: so url is not null in this case? how the heck can that be?

Answer (score 1):

Which jar file is the image in, compared with the class you're using to call `getResource`? If they're loaded by the same classloader, it should be fine.

Have you double-checked that the jar file *actually* contains the file?

Are you sure that your classloader is actually using the jar file at all (rather than .class files directly on disk, for example)?

If you have a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, that would really help. (A console app would be ideal... we don't need to *see* the image, after all.)