# Application does not work when zipped

Tags: java, exception, zip, extract

Basically I just got some results back for an assignment and my results were lower than expected. I was told that when the application was run the images had to be moved and a number of exceptions were thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs12420.aberpizza.gui.FrontGUI.getName(FrontGUI.java:494)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.CPlatformWindow.getInitialStyleBits(CPlatformWindow.java:271)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.CPlatformWindow.initialize(CPlatformWindow.java:228)
```

Well, I checked a lot of times that the runnable jar file worked before sending everything off. And I checked again now and it still does. The only time where things do not work is if I do not extract the contents and attempt to use the runnable jar file from the zipped folder.

I'm assuming that this is the problem, because the images do not appear and things simply do not work properly. But how am I supposed to use images correctly when running the jar from a zipped folder?

This is a question not a rage by the way. I would like to know if my application should or should not be expected to run without extraction whilst using external images?

Just a little edit: To add to my question: how can I get images working if a runnable jar file is being run directly from the zip file. I.e. how can I make the image files/folder go with the runnable jar file to the temporary location?

Comment: You shouldn't have to be able to run from inside a zipped folder, but you _should_ be expected to handle the error gracefully instead of simply throwing a NullPointerException.

Comment: It never occurred to me that it might be run without initially extracting the whole zip document as running from a zip folder famously often produces errors. However you're very right, and in the future I will think back to this and handle potential errors of this nature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, running a file from a zipped folder, will extract your file to a temporary folder and execute it from there. If you have some other files in the archive that your application depends upon, they might not get extracted and hence the error you get.

Comment: If this is the case, what determines which files get extracted?

Comment: Well that is up to the application which is doing the unzipping, in your specific case I trust it to be your MacOSX file manager/browser.

Comment: The markers machine actually. I use windows :p Thanks for the comment!

Comment: In that case, good ol' windows explorer :) It will unpack the files you access in a transparent manner, to "ease" your working process. In doing so, one might take it for granted and overlook that the "zipped folder" he's viewing is not actually a real folder

Comment: By the way, WinZip and other tools have the same effect unless you explicitly unzip everything. They simple extract the file being opened to a temporary folder. In your case, it would have worked if all the resources were inside the main jar.

Comment: @DanMc Regarding your later edit, there is no way for you to force the extraction of all your files when executing only a file while browsing an archive. Just as the person above said, the best way is to include your images in the jar itself. Here is some advice on how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076620/load-image-from-jar-always-null