# Unable to access change of pictures while in jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm using Netbeans and scene builder to make a small game, and all my tests have been working well on my computer, and I wanted to try and test it on another person's computer to try and see how the game looked on a different screen. When my teammate tried to load it on his computer using all the files from my Netbeans, it failed to load because it said that it was unable to access the images I'm changing in the controllers. I only get the same errors when I try to run the JAR file that net beans makes for the project, so I'm assuming if I fix that, it should fix the other. Any ideas on making sure the JAR file will till be able to access the images as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure your images are really included in the .jar (unzip -l xyz.jar)
2. Do not try to open the image-files as plain files (path access) but use the

   myclass.getClass().getResource(fileName)

approach.
See [A related question "Load images from jar: Always null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076620/load-image-from-jar-always-null)