# Unable to locate/open image inside exported jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export, absolute-path

*I have explored every single solution related to this problem on Stack Overflow, and the solutions I encountered worked only in my IDE (Eclipse Mars), but when exported they all failed.*

I have an image file I simply want to load from inside my exported jar.

[image: Project Setup]

As you can see from the project layout, `Images` is a folder directly inside of the project folder `CooldownTrackerJava`. To refer to it, I've tried a variety of methods.

```
//My class' name is AddItemDialog

//Method 1
String filePath = File.separator + "Images" + File.separator + "questionMark.png";
InputStream inputStream = AddItemDialog.class.getResourceAsStream(filePath);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
```

I tried method 1 in a few ways. I tried it with and without the `File.separator` at the start of the filePath. *I understand that the former refers to an absolute path, while the latter is relative.* I also tried moving the Images folder inside of the directory where my class files were.

All of these failed giving me a `NullPointerException` when exported and tested multiple times.

```
//Method 2
String saveLocation = File.separator + "Images" + File.separator + "questionMark.png";    
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource(saveLocation));
```

[As per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076620/load-image-from-jar-always-null) I tried the above method however it still did not work.

I've tried many variations aside from the ones mentioned in this post but none of them have been successful when I exported the jar.

Do I need to add the Images folder to my build path? Should I move it to the `src` folder? Am I missing one obvious step? All suggestions would be highly appreciated. Also here is the layout of the exported jar file.

[image]

Comment: `Method 2` should do the job but you need to move the `Images` folder into `src` making it a package to access.

Comment: Do not use `File.separator()`. Separators for resource paths on the class path is always `/`. If you use Windows you will therefore always get the wrong result.

Comment: @Matthew trying that now.

Comment: @fge Oh I was not aware of that. That may be the key to fixing the issue. I'm using Windows.

Comment: Okay at long last it's finally working :D 

I moved my Images folder into the src folder, and I removed     File.separator() and replaced it with     /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was a two-part effort. Firstly, I moved my `Images` folder into the `src` directory as shown below. Kudos to Matthew.

[image]

I then removed `File.separator` and replaced it with a forward slash`/`. Thanks to fge.

> Do not use File.separator(). Separators for resource paths on the class path is always /. If you use Windows you will therefore always get the wrong result.

I used a variant of method 1 to test it. Both methods will work though.

```
String saveLocation = "/Images/questionMark.png";
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(saveLocation);
try {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```